# How to return uint256 datatype from ink! wasm contract? How to make compatibility with IERC20?

Tags: ink, wasm, pallet-contracts, solidity, solang

IERC20 interface contains methods with uint256 datatype.
If you try to call ink! wasm contract from Solidity (compiled by solang to target subtrate) you will have an issue.

```
interface IERC20{
    function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }
}
```

How to return `u256` data type from rust ink! smart contract to support compatibility with IERC20?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use ethnum crate: https://crates.io/crates/ethnum

Code example:

```
#[ink(message]
pub fn balance(&self, account : AccountId) -> [u128; 2] {
   let balance_u128 : u128 = self.balance_of(account);
   use ethnum::U256;
   let balance_u256: U256 = U256::try_from(b).unwrap();
   balance_u256.0
}
```

It works fine while you will call this contract method from Solidity wasm contract(compiled by solang to substrate target)